# Slew Drive Motor Control

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller

I need to control this motor but i don't understand how to control it. Do I need a controller or just supply 24 V?

[image]

edit: I want to turn on-off and move forward-backward.

Comment: what do you mean by 'control'? Turn it on and off, forwards or backwards? Move it to a set position? Change the speed at which it slews? Change the torque it delivers into a stalled load?

Comment: @Neil_UK I mean turn it on-off and moving forvard-bacward.

Comment: To turn it on, connect the supply. To turn it off, disconnect the supply. To move it in the other direction, connect the supply the other way round.

Comment: @Neil_UK I want to change rotation without changing connection how can i do that and is it enough connect "motor -"-> GND and "motor +" ->24V.

Comment: When I say 'connect the supply the other way round', I mean use electronics - a double pole relay, an H bridge, or whatever, even a switch if you are happy to do it manually, to change the polarity of supply applied to the wires you have got permanently connected to the motor. Connecting motor- to GND and motor+ to +24 V (assuming GND means the -ve end of your +24 V supply) will only get you one direction of rotation.

Comment: @Neil_UK Okey thank you.  In addition how is possible 1.2 rpm for the motor. Isn't it very slow.

Comment: It is very slow. It is obviously a geared motor.